# robotframework : How to ignore failure from --rerunfailed when all tests are passed

Tags: robotframework

I run my robotframework test suite as a teamcity/jenkins build with two simple steps as below

- build step #1: pybot
- build step #2: pybot --rerunfailed Results\output.xml

When all the tests in step-1 are passed, the build fails because step-2 (--rerunfailed) triggers an error ( *[ ERROR ] Collecting failed tests from 'Results\output.xml' failed: All tests passed.*) .

Could someone please suggest how to ignore or overcome this error, so that I can show the build as passed in this case ?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar Problem, i fixed it this way:

```
robot -d %ResultPath% %TestSuitName% || robot --rerunfailed output.xml --output output1.xml -l log.html -r report.html TestSuitName || rebot --rerunmerge --output output.xml -l log.html -r report.html output.xml output1.xml
```

Uses `||` to run those command simultaneously and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Make build step #2 dependent on build step #1 failing. That is, only run `pybot --rerunfailed` if the first `pybot` exited with a non-zero exit status.

The simplest way to do this is to create a custom test runner in bash or python or powershell that does both the running of pybot and re-running of pybot as a single step. You then configure this shell script as a single step.

Another way to do it is to have your second build step either look at the return code of the previous step (if possible), or scans the output.xml to see if there are failures. If there are no failures, it returns without doing any work.

Comment: Thanks Bryan Oakley, for your response. In teamcity, we can configure such dependency for a step on positive scenario [ like 'Only if build status is successful' or 'If all previous steps finished successfully'] but not for failure conditions.

Comment: @senram: my team uses teamcity. We have both the run and rerun steps as a single build step. We have a custom python script that runs pybot, checks the status, and then reruns only if tests fail.

Answer (score 0):

There's robot:skip-on-failure tag. It it sets then a test case will skip for failure and perform if it's ok. It takes RobotFramework 5.0.